# Standard Wordpress Search does not work / Search-results are not displayed / Custom template

Tags: templates, search

My search-results are not displayed. Instead searches show a 404. See https://startupsagainstcorona.com/solutions/ for testing. Can someone help?

What did I do?

1. I implemented the standard WP-search using get_search_form(). This
   worked fine, as you can see on the page.
2. I added the search.php and searchform.php in the root-folder of the template. Those phps came from 
   the twentyseventeen-template of WP, as I am using a custom template and the files have been missing.

   > The searchform-layout changed accordingly.

Unfortuntately, the search.php seems to be inactive in a way. Everytime, entering a search, delivers a 404.

Here the code of the search.php:

```
<get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">

    <header class="page-header">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyseventeen' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .page-header -->

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                /**
                 * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                 * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );

            endwhile; // End of the loop.

            the_posts_pagination(
                array(
                    'prev_text'          => twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) . '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>',
                    'next_text'          => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ),
                    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . ' </span>',
                )
            );

        else :
            ?>

            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></p>
            <?php
                get_search_form();

        endif;
        ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php //get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

And here the code for the searchform.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying search forms in Twenty Seventeen
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

?>

<?php $unique_id = esc_attr( twentyseventeen_unique_id( 'search-form-' ) ); ?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>">
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></span>
    </label>
    <input type="search" id="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
</form>
```

Appreciate any hint.

Best,
Max

Comment: The `action` field of the form is `https://startupsagainstcorona.com/`, shouldn't that be `https://startupsagainstcorona.com/solutions/`?

Comment: Great hint! That was the solution! Changed it and it works :):) Thanks Jos!!

Comment: Please allow me to state that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action` field of the search form refers to `https://startupsagainstcorona.com`, which is the root of the web server.

However, apparently Wordpress is installed at `https://startupsagainstcorona.com/solutions`, which is where the action field should refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try flushing your permalinks. This can be done by visiting the Permalinks under settings and hitting 'Save Changes'

Comment: Just did this but did unfortunately not help. Is it enough to visit the "Permalinks" and hit "Save" without changing? :)